# Increase Div height when checkmark is checked

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

I currently have a fadein/out of a hidden div when a checkmark is checked. I would like to also increase the appropriate div height as well and then remove the same height after the check mark is unchecked. This some snippets of my current code:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$('.checkTax').change(function() {
if ($(this).attr("checked")) {
    $('.prorateTax').fadeIn();
    return;
}
$('.prorateTax').fadeOut();
});
</script>
```

The div whos height needs to be adjusted is: `.article.prorate` . I've tried a few suggestions online and so far nothing is working. If other information is needed to provide a adequate response please let me know.

Edit:
After the various answers I modified the code according to a couple of suggestions and ended up with (which worked perfectly):

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$('.checkTax').change(function() {
if ($(this).attr("checked")) {
    $('.prorateTax').fadeIn();
    $('article.prorate').css( "height", "+=100px" );
}
else
{
    $('.prorateTax').fadeOut();
    $('article.prorate').css( "height", "-=100px" );
}
});
</script>
```

I appreciate everyones help and if I could select more than one green checkmark, I would. Several suggestions given would have worked. I cannot also upvote/downvote as I do not have enough reputation.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To increase height by getting current height of the element you can do this way:

```
$(selector).css( "height", "+=20px" );

$(selector).height( $(selector).height() + 20 );
```

Answer (score 0):

I see You are using jQuery . For manipulating height use :

```
$('selector').css('height', your_value);
```

Comment: So if I wanted to add on height to the existing setting it currently has use: $('.article.prorate').css( "height", "+=20px" ); ? will this work?

Comment: $('.article.prorate').css( "height", parseInt($('.article.prorate').css( "height")) + 20 );

Answer (score 0):

You can also use the more simpler jQuery method .height();

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$('.checkTax').change(function() {
if ($(this).attr("checked")) {
    $('.prorateTax').fadeIn().height(20);
    return;
}
$('.prorateTax').fadeOut().height(0);
});
```